# Wireless headset standard for Dodge Van

Tags: audio, dodge

I just got a 2016 Dodge Caravan that has the DVD entertainment system in it.  It comes with 2 headsets to start with but I'm wanting to get a few more.  It uses a IR interface.  What is the standard that this works on?

I'm not looking for a product req (but feel free to comment some), just trying to get a feel for what I need to look for, what options there are out there, and compatibility issues I'll come across.

Comment: Please post pictures of the headsets. Specifically with any label they may have. They are usually bluetooth, though.

Comment: I updated the question with the interface type.

Answer (score 2):

Really the only thing you need to know is what you've figured out already - the headsets work with IR emmiters built into the entertainment system of the van.  There appears to only be one "standard" and searching for "Dodge Caravan IR headset" will give you tons of choices.

The only thing I would look at is to make sure the headsets are "dual channel" capable.  My van has a dual DVD player so the second row can watch a different movie than the third row.  The headsets must be able to handle and separate the two signals for this setup to work.  Maybe *all* the IR headsets are capable of this and some vendors advertise it heavily while others don't.  The aftermarket headphones I bought have a simple 1/2 switch to pick a channel.

Note that the same headphones will also work in a VW Routan since it's just a re-badged Dodge Caravan, complete with the same DVD entertainment system.